# Generating Optimal Word Combinations from Letters to Maximize Scrabble Score (Based on length of words)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, scrabble

My Goal:

- Given a string of 36 letters, find the combination of words that maximizes the total Scrabble score

Scoring Rules:

- Each word scores the number of letters - 3, multiplied by 5, for words between 4-9 letters
- Words >= 10 letters score a flat 30 points

Sorry I am new to Python or other coding language. I have no idea how to list out all possible combination of words without generating a 36! Permutations - If I do so (silly of course), I can simply continue by splitting the string from the first letter to the last letter to form all possible words (Show in next sections)

My Current Thoughts (Seems extremely inefficient):

*Focus on constrained search space of 4-10 letter words and using a dictionary to prune invalid combinations.*

1. Generate all possible letter combinations of lengths 4-10 letters
2. Filter combinations to valid dictionary words
3. Calculate score for each valid word
4. Find the combination of valid words that maximizes total score

   - Max score is 120 points using 4 words of length 9

Implementation:

- String of 36 letters
- Iterator to generate letter combinations
- Dictionary to check word validity
- Tuple or list to store word combinations
- Function to calculate score for a word combination
- Backtracking search to find optimal combination

**But I ask this question because I seriously want to avoid this inefficient methods**: Imagine I create a 36! Permutations, for each permutation I split the string in a loop to generate all possible combinations of words (tuples), then I compare the score of all tuples to identity the highest possible score a player can generate in any given 36 letters. It seems ridiculous for me to solve a simple (to some extent) game using brutal computation force.

Trying to Avoid with your Suggestions:

- Generating all 36! permutations - infeasible
- Sorting all combinations - inefficient

Comment: What do you mean by "word"? Is it any sequence of letters? Or a sequence that can be found in a dictionary?

Comment: A valid word that can be found in the dictionary, e.g. scrabble dictionary. I am happy enough to use pyenchant or Wordnet (a smaller set of English words) as replacement though

Comment: Thanks for reminding me :). I should clarify my message better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering every permutation of the 36 letters, another approach to
solve this problem is to generate the valid words, and then enumerate all
the combinations of valid words. What are valid words? I will explain.

Given a dictionary, and a list of 36 letters, the valid words are all the words
in the dictionary that can be constructed by using the 36 letters. After finding
the valid words, a backtracking algorithm can be used to enumerate all possible
combinations (with repetition) of the valid words that can be combined together
by using the 36 letters.

The time complexity of this algorithm is polynomial in the size of the set of valid words.
Since at most nine four-letter words can be used as matches for the 36 letters,
it means the algorithm has an O(n^9) runtime, where n is the size of
the set of valid words.

Here is the implementation in Python (note that I am using the Linux dictionary file, so you
can change the dictionary file if you are on a different platform). After the algorithm finishes, the last set of words printed will be one of the optimal solutions. If you only want to check if there is a solution with 120 points, that should run quickly, since the valid words count will be low, and it only needs to check for combinations of up to four words. You can play with the `MAX_WORD_SIZE` and `MIN_WORD_SIZE` variables to see what gives the best results. You can also set the `LETTERS` to whatever you want. I just initialized it randomly from ASCII characters.

```py
import random
import string
from typing import List, Dict
from collections import Counter

DICT_FILE = "/usr/share/dict/words"
MIN_WORD_SIZE = 4
MAX_WORD_SIZE = 10
LETTERS = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(36))

def is_valid(word: str, letter_counts: Dict[str, int]):
    for c in word:
        if letter_counts[c] == 0:
            return False
        letter_counts[c] -= 1
    return True


def valid_words(letters: str) -> List[str]:
    valid = []
    letter_counts = Counter(letters)
    with open(DICT_FILE) as f:
        for line in f:
            word = line.strip()
            if (
                "'" in word or 
                len(word) < MIN_WORD_SIZE or
                len(word) > MAX_WORD_SIZE
            ):
                continue
            if is_valid(word, letter_counts.copy()):
                valid.append(word)
    return valid


def remove_letters(word: str, counts: Dict[str, int]):
    for c in word:
        counts[c] -= 1

def add_letters(word: str, counts: Dict[str, int]):
    for c in word:
        counts[c] += 1

def find_optimal(valid_words: List[str], letters: str):
    curr_words = []
    counts = Counter(letters)
    n = len(valid_words)

    def find_words(i: int, num_letters: int):
        if i == n or num_letters < 4:
            return
        for j, word in enumerate(valid_words[i:], i):
            if is_valid(word, counts.copy()):
                remove_letters(word, counts)
                curr_words.append(word)
                yield from find_words(j, num_letters - len(word))
                yield curr_words.copy()
                curr_words.pop()
                add_letters(word, counts)

    yield from find_words(0, len(letters))


def score(word_combos: List[str]):
    return sum(
        min(
            (len(word) - 3) * 5, 
            30,
        ) for word in word_combos
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    valid = valid_words(LETTERS)
    latest_highest_score = 0
    latest_best_words = []
    for word_combos in find_optimal(valid, LETTERS):
        curr_score = score(word_combos)
        if curr_score >= latest_highest_score:
            latest_highest_score = curr_score
            latest_best_words = word_combos
            print(word_combos, latest_highest_score)
```

Comment: Impressive! May I ask how you create a dictionary of words?

Comment: You can use a text file of words. I used [`/usr/share/dict/words`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)), a newline-delimited list of dictionary words. The algorithm above reads through every word in the file, discarding any of the words that are too short, too long, that cannot be spelled given the 36 letters, or that have an apostrophe. Any words that are left over and that can be spelled from the 36 letters are added to the list of valid words.